# how to get plaintext value use simple_html_dom.php?

Tags: php

I want to get the following strong element's value "hello", the only unique value is em class name, the strong's class name maybe duplicate，how to get the "hello" via simple_html_dom.php ？　I　get it via

```
$html->find('em[class=b]')
```

just get "hi", not what I want, anyone have good ideas via simple_html_dom ? thanks.

```
<strong class="a">
<em class="b">hi</em>
hello
</strong>
```

Comment: look at this library http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ or http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$element = $html->find('em[class=a]');
$element->innertext;
```

I've not actually tested that but it should work based on [documentation here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#frag_access_special)

Comment: Hi Vince, thanks for your reply, I have tried, but it not work. any other suggestion ? thanks